# Why is my returned response not matching the type inferred?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to return an array of Random picture objects from [Unsplash API](https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-js). My useState hook doesn't recognise the response coming although I inferred the hook's expected values.

```
let randomPictures: Random[] = [];
```

```
const Flow = () => {
  const [images, setImage]: [Random[], (images: Random[]) => void] = React.useState(randomPictures);
  const [error, setError]: [string, (error: string) => void] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      api.photos.getRandom({ count: 10 })
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result.response);
          setImage(result.response); // Argument of type 'Random | Random[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Random[]'.
        })
        .catch(() => {
          const errorMessage = 'Something has gone wrong';
          setError(errorMessage);
          console.log(error);
        })
         }, []);

  return (
    <Box>
      <Center>
        {images.map((photo: Photo) => {
          <Image borderRadius="md" />
        })}
      </Center>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

`result.response` should return an array of 10 random objects, but why am I getting the error ?
I even tried making a RandomResponse type with the expected values for the response and tried replacing the Random type, but it still didn't work.

Here's a preview of the response I got from logging it to console.
[image]

I'm new to typescript and I exhausted the rate limits yesterday while I was testing. I don't know what to do and I don't want to type it as `any`.

Comment: TypeScript types are mostly used to do compile-time checks. Comparing with the actual response will not help a lot. What does the return type of `api.photos.getRandom({ count: 10 })` look like?

Comment: ```result: ApiResponse<Random | Random[]>```  a Random type response. The Random type is implemented in the unsplash module.

Comment: Should I just put it as type ```any``` then ?

Answer (score 0):

Based solely off the error message you are seeing, my suggestion would be to change your code to this. Reasons for the changes are mentioned in the code as well.

```
// to remove the possibility that it can be undefined
if (result.response) {
  // to make sure you're setting Random[] even if the response was a single object
  setImage(
    Array.isArray(result.response) ? result.response : [result.response]
  );
}
```

Comment: I get the same error :(

Comment: This is the best I can do without the actual code. If you can post a codesandbox or any other way to reproduce the problem, I can take a look.

Comment: I made a [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEpxAEwPYFtkDeyAvgNwBQoksiKAggA7CoQDOD2IrEAPACoA+QuWTIobDlwgB+AFzI+FYuXIwAriARhgnZNzABJXHADmEABTBjZ1vPRY8AbQC6ASnkA3bMEzDyy1Q0tHRBkMzB7HFxzd2QABSg8YG4eRmYJThTIvGQAHzQMKJcBIQIRMQgwNShQhKTuADpxVmwAGw8LMtFRZslueRdy4lclFXDs6NdyhrAACwgQc2a1VrBkAF5S8tEETLaIBtbsEyW2FbAmjKkR7eRgGGRT1nPL9kyIV2Fu7oB6H+QwNhkMYANYoZ7iZAAT2wagA5JD9NoQCYCg5cC5kBAOqF7gD5hU3lJkAB3OCsZBwPSgEytFDYABGACsIFpbqJ9EZTBZ2d06FAoHAoQ1kvzBVCni9eu9PtJCVKrtxkANlqtXn0IM5eTdvspRMMgA) with mocks. The error is gone.

Comment: All the source code are in this public repo https://github.com/SuitlessStan/Library. Thank you for your help, but I inferred the objects to type ```any``` :(.